# I'm Trying To add this on A onStart method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onstart

I'm trying to put this code in a `onStart` method. I tried several things but can't seem to find a way... if I put it on a `onStart` method the error is:

> cannot return value from a method with a void result type

I did try changing it into a int, any ideas?

I tried to do `public int onStart...` method, but didn't work out very well

Note: I'm to new to Android, this my seem a obvious answer to you, but unfortunately not to me.

thanks in advance!!

```
public  String getGiphyViews() {
    String id_image = "qi6Yrko";
    String source = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://imgur.com/" + id_image);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("views")) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        }

        in.close();

        source = str.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String views = source.split("<span class=\"views-" + id_image  + "\">")[1].split("<")[0];

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.views);
    assert t != null;
    t.setText(views);

    return views;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for your `onStart` method

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you tried to put it in `onStart`? Were you calling it or replacing `onStart` with this code?

Comment: where do you want to use the return value exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the `onStart` method return type from void to int. This method is part of the life cycle of any Android `Activity`. With implementing this method, you basically `override` the parent method. And when you override a method, you are always obligated to keep the same return type, method name and arguments. There is no way around it. So it would help if you explain why you would even want this to return anything? I would suggest, in case you need some value from the `Activity`, that you save the value inside the `Activity` and then pass the value with a getter method.

For further explanation please check the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a method inside method. Put this code outside onStart() and call this method inside onStart like this:

```
String myView;

protected void onStart (){
    myView = getGiphyViews();
}

public  String getGiphyViews() {
...
}
```